# Creating A JTextField Input Validator

Tags: java, swing, inputverifier

I am trying to create a `JTextField` input validator following [Building a Swing Validation Package with InputVerifier](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20551.html). I have taken all the class on that page an am now trying to use the `NotEmptyValidator` found [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20552.html). I have a `JFrame` and a `JTextField`. I am trying to use this package but its giving me an error.The code is shown below:

```
public class ValidateTest extends JFrame {
public JTextField field;

public ValidateTest() {
    this.field = new JTextField();
    this.field.setInputVerifier(new NotEmptyValidator(this, this.field,
            "No Empty Value"));// The line showing an error.

    this.setTitle("ValidateTest");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(200, 200);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(this.field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    ValidateTest vt = new ValidateTest();
   }
 }
```

**NOTE:** I have just taken the classes as they are. The only code I have added is above.

**My Questions:**
1. How do I instantiate the `NotEmptyValidator`? I mean I provided the `JTextField`and the `String` but don't know how to do it with the `JDialog`.

2. How do we resolve this error and what went wrong here?

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard The error message is shown in the IDE;Your -1 was not necessary here! A good look at the commented line will review everything to a programmer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve the problem by passing the following to the constructor in `NotEmptyValidator` class. Below is how I got it:

```
        this.field.setInputVerifier(new NotEmptyValidator(new JDialog(this), this.field,
            "No Empty Value"));
```